# How do you do a condition SQL left join based on the status of the second table?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, jdbc, left-join

So for example I have two tables

```
Person Table
ID : Name
1 : Bob
2 : Jane
3 : Mike
4 : John
5: Mary
```

I then also have (current is actually an integer but I used text to make it more readable):

```
Job Table
ID : Name : PersonID : JobStatus
1 : Plumber : 1 : current
2 : Doctor : 2 : past
3 : Driver : 2 : current
4 : Cook : 3 : current
5: Programmer : 5 : past
```

I would like to join the two tables so that I can get a list of everyone, but I only want to include current jobs with the left join. In other words I want the result to be:

```
Bob : Plumber : current
Jane : Driver : current
Mike : Cook : current
John : :  
Mary : :
```

How can I do this with a join. I tried doing:

```
SELECT 
  person.name, job.name, job.status 
FROM 
  person
LEFT JOIN 
  job ON person.id=job.person.id
```

But the problem is that in this case I will see two entries for Jane, one for her past job of Doctor as well as her new job of Driver. And if I add a where clause such as:

```
WHERE job.status='current'
```

Then it removes removes John and Mary from the list.

How can I write a join that will show all the people yet only include jobs that are current?

Comment: Boy did Jane take a BIG demotion... from Doctor to Driver? What happened?!

Answer (score 3):

At least in Oracle you should be able to do this:

```
SELECT 
  person.name, job.name, job.status 
FROM 
  person
LEFT JOIN 
   job ON person.id=job.personId AND job.status = 'current';
```

so when `person.id=job.person.id AND job.status = 'current'` the join is made, and when that condition is false you only get `person` data.

I don't know if MySQL supports composite conditions in `ON` clauses but I guess so, it is not exactly groundbreaking technology.

**UPDATE:**

Looks like it is supported, read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html

Comment: That's the issue, if I do that then it won't include people without jobs. In other words John and Mary will not appear in the results.

Comment: Why wouldn't they? You have an outer join and the join condition is not met so the db should return the values in the main table.

Comment: I can't believe I missed this; I've taught SQL to so many people, and usually cover this exact type of thing. I guess answering things late at night is a bad idea...

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this; the best option depends on your database, and how the differing methods perform.

**Method 1: Left Join with OR**

```
SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN job AS j ON j.personId = p.id AND j.status = 'current';
-- Returns all persons, and only jobs w/ value 'current'
-- If the filter on j.status were in the WHERE clause, it would remove non-matching
```

**Method 2: Two queries with UNION ALL (this removes rows w/ no current or null vals)**

```
SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN job AS j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status = 'current'
OR j.status IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN job AS j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status IS NULL;
```

**Method 2b: Two queries with UNION ALL (this retains rows w/ no current or null vals)**

```
SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
INNER JOIN job AS j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE j.status = 'current'
OR j.status IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN job AS j ON j.personId = p.id
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (SELECT 1 FROM jobs AS t WHERE t.personId=p.Id AND t.status='current')
GROUP BY p.Id; 
-- GROUP BY ensures we only get one row back per person, but will be random if there are multiples
```

**Method 3: Sub-selects**

```
SELECT p.name, j.name, j.status
FROM person AS p
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT x.name
  FROM job AS x
  WHERE x.status = 'current'
) AS j;
```

Comment: What happens if say Mary is linked to a previous job? In other words Mary has Job programmer but with a status that is neither current or null (say something like potential, past, etc.)

Comment: Well, what would you want it to do? Depending on how you want it to behave, I would handle it differently. Method 1 would exclude Mary from the results, as would Method 2, but Method 3 would still return Mary.

Comment: I just realized that the first two queries should be modified (didn't realize you wanted all the users, sorry). In fact, the first method wouldn't work for what you want, since you have multiple rows, however the second would do what you want, if you modify the second query. Let me update the orig response.

Comment: I'm a moron; @gpeche is actually correct; put the job restriction in the ON clause, and it will JOIN only where that evaluates to TRUE. Therefore, it will return all persons, and only jobs where all values in the ON clause on satisfied. This is a case where putting a filter in the ON clause behaves differently than the WHERE clause. I can't believe I messed that up. Anyway, I'll leave up the other methods, in case it helps learn differing SQL tricks. I updated Method 1 to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

```
   Select p.name, j.name,j.status 
     From person p 
Left Join
         (Select name,status,personId 
            From job 
            Where status ='current'
         ) j On p.id = j.personId;
```

Can you try this query?

Comment: How will John and Mary appear in this query?

Comment: Is it working, if yes, then I shall explain otherwise will try some other query :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  person.name, job.name, job.status 
FROM 
  person
LEFT JOIN 
  job ON person.id=job.person.id
WHERE CASE WHEN job.status IS NULL THEN '@' WHEN job.status ='current' THEN '@' else job.status END = '@'
```

Comment: I don't understand this query in hose the cases would work but in any case it doesn't include any Mary and John

Comment: For Mary and John job status will be null so query will return those rows. In this query I’m taking the rows for which  job.status is current (if available) or job.status is null only. If anyone of the condition satisfied then case expression will return @ otherwise it will return job.status